# Get the result of a Shell Commands within C

Tags: c, shell, mixing

I'm trying to find a function to call a system command (shell command) and get back its result in a C program.
I only found functions like system but these don't return the result of the command.

I just know it in perl : my $results = ``my shell command` ;

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `popen()`, at least on POSIX (Linux etc) systems. In Windows, a different solution is likely needed.